# Javascript date format using string month

Tags: javascript

All the other topics on date format assume that dates are entered as integers.

I'm writing a script (Linux) that requires the month to be a string (Jan, Feb, Mar etc) and need to validate the dates.

I've written a clunky routine that extracts the month, determines the month number and then does the comparison but I was hoping there might be something neater out there to do this? I thought I had seen something about using a 'format' method but I can't find it now...

I've tried this but it fails miserably:

```
var checkDate1 = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
var checkDate2 = document.getElementById('toDate').value;

tmpDate1 = new Date(checkDate1);
tmpDate2 = new Date(checkDate2);

if (tmpDate1 < tmpDate2) {
```

where a typical field entry will be '12-may-2012', for example.

NOTE: I don't have access to add any fancy, whizzy libraries to the system so have to make do with the vanilla stuff.

Comment: please read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: Read that 27 times and counting - not helping. That's how I got the example in my OP.

Comment: @JakubOboza w3schools ? really ? The worse website ever ? You, take a look at that : http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @DieVarDump, I totally agree with this website. Lol. I feel bad for the poor souls that have wasted money on their certificates. Everything you could ever want to know about JavaScript from the authentic source: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Actually, `Date.parse('12-may-2012')` seems to work on Chrome. But I had answered a similar question and while answering, I came to know that this was implementation dependent. So, if you aren't targeting general public, you may want to use this. I repeat this isn't cross-browser.

Comment: Chrome also accepts `Date.parse('May 12, 2012');`, `Date.parse('5/12/2012');`, `Date.parse('5.12.2012');`, and many others I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, to be parsed in the constructor, string Date must have the format : D, d M Y H:i:s

Now it'll be : Tue, 29 May 2012 15:22:59

If you want to stay with string, you'll have to make a fancy function that parse your value, and find what day will be the 29 May of 2012.

**Another method** ( and easier ) is to create a new Date, parse you value and use the on of the other constructors

```
var today = '05-29-2012',
    aToday = today.split('-'),
    dToday = new Date(aToday[2], aToday[0], aToday[1], 0, 0, 0, 0),

    tomorrow = '05-30-2012',
    aTomorrow = tomorrow.split('-'),
    dTomorrow = new Date(aTomorrow[2], aTomorrow[0], aTomorrow[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

if (dTomorrow.getTime() > dToday.getTime() ) {
    console.log('Tomorrow is tomorrow'); 
} else {
    console.log('Tomorrow is not tomorrow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but you're still assuming month is 5, rather than 'May'. I've got something similar to the above already - just hoped there was something simpler for what must be a common process.